# Sorting in Elastic

Tags: elasticsearch

The essence of the question: There is a field 'payed_promo' in which the date is stored in UNIX TIME format (1508904244). I do sorting on ElasticSearch:

```
'_script' => [
            'type' => 'date',
            'script'  => "if(doc['payed_promo'].value > 1508904244 ) doc['payed_promo'].value",
            'order' => 'desc'
        ],
```

He gives me an error: failed to parse field [type] How can I fix it? What type of data should I put?
As I understood there is only type: number or string, if so, then another error occurs:

```
{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"null_pointer_exception","reason":null}],"type":"search_phase_execution_exception","reason":"all shards failed","phase":"query","grouped":true,"failed_shards":[{"shard":0,"index":"services","node":"qWnjNlxwTAOgCizNse3Gyg","reason":{"type":"null_pointer_exception","reason":null}}]},"status":500}
```